# WPF - datagridview options

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagridview

Need to represent a two column table. Maybe just for reference at this stage - or with the functionality that a double click presents a combobox essentially on that field with all the possible values that can be entered.

Is datagridview the best option for this in WPF or what else could I do to represent the data?

Cheers,

Comment: DataGridView is a windows forms control - the WPF equivalent is named DataGrid (you can use the windows control with WPF though). It's bundled with .net 4.0 now, although I'm still using the WPFToolKit version (you can find it on Codeplex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say datagridview is the way to go. You can create your own custom columns. Here's a quick example:

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707061

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use something that's already available and pretty easy to use, check out SourceGrid.  I've used it in WinForms and WPF applications, though the latter requires using WindowsFormsHost.

SourceGrid: http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/